There are five students S1,S2,S3,S4 and S5 they are seated in maths
There are five students $S_1$,$S_2$,$S_3$,$S_4$ and $S_5$ in a music class and for them there are five seats $R_1$, $R_2$, $R_3$, $R_4$ and $R_5$ arranged in a row, where initially the seat $R_i$ is allotted to the student $S_i$, $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. But, on the examination day, the five students are randomly allotted the five seats.
The probability that only $S_1$ is given his previouly alotted seat and  none of the other students get the seats previously alotted to them is?
i tried solving the question but it seems that a topic derangement is used here can someone please explain that to me.

Derangements

Dhruv, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read this thread and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed because it is a low-quality question.

Title says math, body says music. Which is it? (Of course it doesn't matter, but such carelessness makes one wonder, why care?)

The word derangement means that nothing is in its original place. It sort of matches with non-mathematical usage of the word (that's how I remember it).
If $S_1$ is in the right place guaranteed, we are trying to count how many derangements of the other 4 people there are. One way to do this is to count all the non-derangements instead (and take it away from 24, the total number of arrangements of any kind). You could have:

4 people in place. There is only 1 way to do this
3 people in place is impossible, since 3 in place fixes the final person also in place
2 people in place. There are ${4}\choose{2}$ choices for which pair gets fixed, and then the other pair goes the wrong way around, so 6 ways for this to happen.
1 person in place. So now we need to count how many derangements of the remaining 3 are possible.

Okay, so we do a similar tactic for derangements of 3 people:

3 people in place. There is only 1 way to do this.
2 people in place is impossible, since 2 in place fixes the final person also in place
1 person in place. There are 3 choices for the 1 person in place, the other two are swapped with each other.

So there are 4 ways to not derange 3 people. So there are $3!-4=2$ ways to derange 3 people.
Returning to working with the 4 people, with exactly 1 in place and the other 3 deranged, we see that there were 4 choices for the 1 person in place, and then 2 ways to derange the rest, so 8 ways to do this overall.
Out of the $4!=24$ ways to arrange $S_2,...,S_5$, we have 1+6+8=15 non-derangements. So there are 24-15=9 derangements, and the probability is therefore $\frac{9}{24}$. So the probability that only $S_1$ is in the right seat is $\frac{1}{5}\times\frac{9}{24}=\frac{3}{40}$

There's various ways to count derangements in general https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements

Daniel, please do not answer low-quality questions.
